# Tikz: Flowchart of thesis structure

Tags: tikz-pgf, flow-charts

Can someone help me make a flowchart of a thesis structure please, which should look something like this:

[image: Structure of thesis]

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436)!  This site works best as a helping hand for when you get stuck with something. Questions like this, that look like "please do this complicated thing for me" tend not to get answers because they require a great deal of effort on the part of the community. To make the most of this site, it would help if you made some substantive efforts please and show what you have done so far with a [Minimal Working Example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228).

Comment: Drawing this isn't the hardest. TikZ can do this with a few chains. This site also has similar diagrams done with `forest`. The most interesting part will be to use the existing `\part`s and `\chapter`s which is also dependent on the document class and packages used. This flowchart will at some point not fit on a normal letter/A4 page. How should this be solved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I guess you are looking for something like this. But do mind the comments above: they are very useful for further questions.

An example MWE would be something like this:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

\usepackage[a4paper,margin=2cm,landscape]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,shapes.geometric}

\begin{document}
    
    \begin{tikzpicture}[block/.style={rectangle,rounded corners,minimum height=10mm, minimum width=35mm, text width=35mm, align=center, thick, font=\sffamily\footnotesize}]
        \node[draw, fill=gray!40, block] (s) at (0,0) {\textbf{Part I \\ Preface}};
            \node[draw, block, below of=s, xshift=10mm, yshift=-5mm] (s1) {1 \\ Introduction \& Problem Statement};
            \node[draw, block, below of=s1, yshift=-5mm] (s2) {2 \\ Research Paradigm};
            \draw[-{Stealth}, thick] ([xshift=1em]s.south west) |- (s1.west)    ;
            \draw[-{Stealth}, thick] ([xshift=1em]s.south west) |- (s2.west)    ;

        \node[draw, fill=gray!40, block, right of=s, xshift=40mm] (a) {\textbf{Part II \\ Theoretical Framework}};
            \node[draw, block, below of=a, xshift=10mm, yshift=-5mm] (a1) {3 \\ Recommender Systems};
            \node[draw, block, below of=a1, yshift=-5mm] (a2) {4 \\ Artificial Neural Networks};
            \node[draw, block, below of=a2, yshift=-5mm] (a3) {5 \\ Evaluation Methods};
            \draw[-{Stealth}, thick] ([xshift=1em]a.south west) |- (a1.west)    ;
            \draw[-{Stealth}, thick] ([xshift=1em]a.south west) |- (a2.west)    ;
            \draw[-{Stealth}, thick] ([xshift=1em]a.south west) |- (a3.west)    ;

        \node[draw, fill=gray!40, block, right of=a, xshift=40mm] (b) {\textbf{Part III \\ Methodology}};
            \node[draw, block, below of=b, xshift=10mm, yshift=-5mm] (b1) {6 \\ Data};
            \node[draw, block, below of=b1, yshift=-5mm] (b2) {7 \\Models};
            \draw[-{Stealth}, thick] ([xshift=1em]b.south west) |- (b1.west)    ;
            \draw[-{Stealth}, thick] ([xshift=1em]b.south west) |- (b2.west)    ;

        \node[draw, fill=gray!40, block, right of=b, xshift=40mm] (c) {\textbf{Part IV \\ Results}};
            \node[draw, block, below of=c, xshift=10mm, yshift=-5mm] (c1) {8 \\ Model Performance Evaluation};
            \node[draw, block, below of=c1, yshift=-5mm] (c2) {9 \\Discussion, Implications \& Conlcusions};
            \node[draw, block, below of=c2, yshift=-5mm] (c3) {10 \\ Future Research};
            \draw[-{Stealth}, thick] ([xshift=1em]c.south west) |- (c1.west)    ;
            \draw[-{Stealth}, thick] ([xshift=1em]c.south west) |- (c2.west)    ;
            \draw[-{Stealth}, thick] ([xshift=1em]c.south west) |- (c3.west)    ;
            
        \draw[-{Stealth}, thick] (s.east) -- (a.west);
        \draw[-{Stealth}, thick] (a.east) -- (b.west);
        \draw[-{Stealth}, thick] (b.east) -- (c.west);
    \end{tikzpicture}
    
\end{document}
```

This example doesn't use the `chain` or `forest` options, but just plain `tikz` commands. Like it has been said: the picture doesn't fit on a *portrait* orientation. This example will produce a *landscape* page.

[image: flowchart thesis]