# How to make an outline in `forest`?

Tags: forest

[image]

I want to make an outline as the image shows. I have reused one of the available templates.
The code is as follows:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage[edges]{forest}
\usetikzlibrary{shadows}
\tikzset{every shadow/.style={shadow xshift=5pt,shadow yshift=-5pt}}
\begin{document}

\begin{forest}
  forked edges,
  for tree={
            l sep+=10pt,
             grow'=east,
              drop shadow,
            font=\sffamily, rounded corners, top color=gray!25, bottom color=gray!10, edge+={darkgray, line width=1pt}, draw=darkgray, align=center, anchor=children},
  before packing={where n children=3{calign child=2, calign=child edge}{}},
  before typesetting nodes={where content={}{coordinate}{}},
  where level<=0{line width=2pt}{line width=1pt},
  [\textbf{Outline}, 
     [Section 1
     [Subsection 1.1]
     [Subsection 1.2]
     ]
        [Section 2
        [Subsection 2.1
        [Subsection 2.1.1]
        ]
        [Subsection 2.2
        [Subsection 2.2.1]
        ]
        ]
          [Section 3
          [Subsection 3.1]
          [Subsection 3.2]
     ]
      ] 
    ]
    ]
     ]
\end{forest}
\end{document}
```

Can someone guide me as to how I can modify the LaTeX code similar to the image please?

Comment: I answered a similar question some time ago, but didn't use `forest`. Maybe you can adapt the code to fit your requirements https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/676688/tikz-flowchart-of-thesis-structure/676706#676706:

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps you want the `folder` style. The only tricky part is disconnecting the **Outline** node from the Section nodes. That requires adjusting the `edge path` with a shift to the initial point.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[edges]{forest}

\begin{document}
    \begin{forest}
    for tree={
        font=\sffamily,
        s sep=1mm,
        l sep=8mm,
        folder,
        grow'=east,
        edge=-stealth,
        if level=1
            {draw, rounded corners, minimum height=8mm, minimum width=2cm,
                edge path={\noexpand\path [draw, \forestoption{edge}]([shift={(\forestregister{folder indent},-1)}]!u.south west)  |- (.child anchor);}}
            {}
    }
[\textbf{Outline}
    [Section 1      
        [Subsection 1.1]
            [Subsection 1.2]
    ]
    [Section 2
        [Subsection 2.1
            [Subsection 2.1.1]
        ]
        [Subsection 2.2
            [Subsection 2.2.1]
        ]
    ]
    [Section 3
        [Subsection 3.1]
        [Subsection 3.2]
    ]
] 
\end{forest}
\end{document}
```

Comment: if I add 7 sections and its four to five subsections then it exceeds the page limit (I am making outline as a stand-alone figure). Can you please suggest some options on that?

Comment: @user3582228: You can add `s sep=1mm` (or other length) to the `for tree` options. You can also reduce `minimum height` for the sections.

Comment: Thank you. I change s sep=1mm but still I can not see section 7. I also reduce min height but not working. Following [https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/403183/standalone-tikz-proper-size-to-include], I tried to change other options but its not working. Please suggest more options.

Comment: I also try with \documentclass[multi=PAGE]{standalone}, it shows all sections but then how can I have a cropped figure with standalone?

Comment: You can try `s sep=0mm` (or -.5mm). Since this issue is different from your original question, if that doesn't work I suggest you post a new question. You can link this one and include your current code.

Comment: I have solved that issue by including \begin{PAGE}%
\begin{adjustbox}{width=250cm, height=450cm, keepaspectratio}. Is there any possibility to remove small line after Outline and directly starting from Section 1? I can remove Outline but that small vertical line stays.

Comment: @user3582228: Too long for a comment. I edited my response.